# What is a substitute for MessageBox.Show for ASP.NET MVC5 web apps

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, popup, azure-web-app-service

I just built a web-app using ASP.NET MVC-5 and published on Azure. However all the MessageBox.Show that I used within catch blocks to validate non-empty doesn't work anymore after I published.

```
catch(ArgumentNullException ae){
    MessageBox.Show("No empty fields.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning, MessageBoxResult.OK, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Is there a quick substitute for this? Because I used a lot of MessageBox.Show.

Comment: No such thing in MVC.. MVC code executes on the server side. Better off finding a logging service of your liking and go with that.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show` is for `Windows Forms Application` you can use many other plugins or custom popup.

Comment: Showing alert (message box) for validation is a bad way of coding as it is very intrusive and irritating. There are many javascript frameworks which does the validation in a simple user friendly way.

Comment: No such thing within `ASP.Net MVC`, you can consider using `alert` within `javascript` or `jquery`.

Comment: As mentioned above, there is no such "direct" thing to replace MessageBox.Show. What you can do is, use a modal popup to display the message. All the other parameters can be taken care of (like buttons/ icon etc) by designing them in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `cshtml` page add this

```
@Html.Raw(TempData["msg"])
```

and in your `controller` `action` add this and return the `view`

```
TempData["msg"] = "<script>alert('Hi this is a message');</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Usman's answer is quite useful. If you use Bootstrap you can use modal, Write your own one will be tough but you can get many alert plugin in jQuery, Bootstrap or whatever framework you use.